# The name 'dgDataGrid' does not exist in the current context C# ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I get the following error in my C# code:

```
The name 'dgDataGrid' does not exist in the current context
```

The bottom two lines are the lines that reference it:

```
    drDataRow[mbNumCount + 1] = rvRowValue;
        }
        raDataTable.Rows.Add(drDataRow);
        tsseg++;
    }
    dgDataGrid.DataSource = raDataTable;
    dgDataGrid.DataBind();
```

Screenshot of the "design" http://i44.tinypic.com/jhez46.png

Please advise me as I am rather stuck on this one..

Designer.cs code:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace New_Solution
{


public partial class Default
{

    /// <summary>
    /// form1 control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm form1;
    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView dgDataGrid;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem can be that dgDataGrid is not automatically added in designer.cs file. If that is case add it in designer manually.

Add these line to your default.aspx.designer.cs file

```
        /// <summary>
        /// dgDataGrid control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView dgDataGrid;
```

Comment: Can you ellobarate? This sounds promising, theres no reference in the designer.cs file how would I go about adding one?

Comment: Thanks, unfortuantley I still get the same error; I have copied my designer.cs code into the original question

Comment: Please visit this link http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/07/tip-regenerate-aspx-designer-cs-files-when-corrupted/

Comment: Thank you! Unfortantly more problems now but at least it compiles!

Comment: If mine is not adding it automatically, I have to do it for every single control?